# Boundary value problems for differential inclusions with fractional order

Tags: metric-spaces

[the probleme is on page 156][1]
*Benchohra, Mouffak; Hamani, Samira*, [**Boundary value problems for differential inclusions with fractional order**](http://dx.doi.org/10.7151/dmdico.1099), Discuss. Math., Differ. Incl. Control Optim. 28, 147-164 (2008). [ZBL1181.26012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1181.26012).I'm having technical problems or just lack of knowledge problems, so I would appreciate your help.
the problem::
let $v_{*}\in F$, and for every $w \in F$, we have 
$$|v_{n}-v_{*}| \leq |v_{n}-w|+|w-v_{*}|...(1)$$

Then, 
$$|v_{n}-v_{*}| \leq d(v_{n},F)...(2)$$
and $d(x,A):=\inf\lbrace|x-y|,~~y \in A\rbrace$

So the problem I'm having is how to get from (1) to (2).
I don't know what to do to get to (2).

**I'm really desperate and I would be more than thankful for any idea.**

[the problem is on page 156][1]: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=M.%20Benchohra%20and%20S.%20Hamani%2C%20Boundary%20value%20problems%20for%20differential%20inclusions%20with%20fractional%20order&btnG=

Comment: The first equation always holds in metric spaces, it is the triangular inequality.

Comment: @Dog_69 And? How is that relevant? This problem isn't limited to metric spaces.

Comment: the first one is clear, I'm asking how to get from (1) to (2).

Comment: I'm new here @Dog_69 . so please pardon me if i did any mistake.

Comment: What are $F$ and $v_n$ ?

Comment: Equation $(1)$ doesn't imply equation $(2)$, as you've stated the problem. Does $v_*$ have any other defining condition than being an element of $F$? Otherwise the only statement you could make is that $d(v_n,F) \leq |v_n-v_*|$ (the reverse inequality of $(2)$), by the definition of $\inf$. Is the reverse inequality what you meant?

Comment: @ jawheele  yep that what i thought too ... but i found it as it is in an artical .. and i dont know how or why they have concluded that...F is a multivalued map (i.e.$F(t,y_{*}(t))$).

Comment: @ippiki-ookami  F is a multivalued map (i.e.F(t,y_{*}(t))). $F : J \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Could you give a reference to this article ?

Comment: @DonThousan If it is a general property it can't imply any special relation, otherwise the latter would be true always.

Comment: @ippiki-ookami  yes I do its  title is: M. Benchohra and S. Hamani, Boundary values problems for differential inclusions with fractional order

Comment: @ippiki-ookami here is the URL of the artical ::https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=M.+Benchohra+and+S.+Hamani%2C+Boundary+value+problems+for+differential+inclusions+with+fractional+order&btnG=

Comment: So I took a look, but am as confused as you are.

Comment: @ippiki-ookami  hhh well i can relate to that ..and thank you very much for trying.

Comment: @hanaachan Usually, mathematicians don't have any problem answer question, don't matter who asks. My advice is to write an email to one of the authors explaining your doubt. I'm sure they will be glad.

Comment: @hanaachan yes maybe I should heed your advice and ask them .. it doesn't hurt to try right. thank u.

Answer (score 1):

From (1) there is no way to get (2). This is probably just a mistake. Since $w \in F$ difference $|v_n-w|$ almost more than infinum. To this is added positive number limited by the size of the set $F$. $d(v_n,F)$ is lower limit.